# Can I use a Shimano BL-MT200 lever on a Shimano BR-M446 brake caliper?

Tags: brakes, hydraulic-disc-brake

I have a leakage on my lever, and can't find any Shimano BR-M446s for sale. Was wondering if Shimano BL-MT200s were compatible.

Comment: I want to do the same thing. How did it go?

Comment: @SimãoFerreira The user is greyed out which means deleted, so I'm afraid there won't be an answer because he or she will never get notified. Based on the only answer, it probably worked and the only concern would be fitting a lower-tier groupset, so looks and feel might be a little different. However, not even their lowest tier _Tourney_ is terrible based on my experience, so it's probably not a big deal to go "one down" on an entry level bike. As you wouldn't really notice between 105 and Ultegra just by feel...

Answer (score 1):

The corresponding lever for the *ALIVIO* BR-M446 caliper [appears to be](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/alivio-t4000.html) either the BL-T445 or the BL-M425 (depending on the size; 3 finger vs. 2).  You might have more luck searching for those product numbers instead.

The [*ACERA* BL-MT200](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/acera-m390/BL-MT200.html) seems to have very similar specs to the [*ALIVIO* BL-T445](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/alivio-t4000/BL-T445.html), though based on the angle to the clamp it may stand off the bars a bit further.  Specifically they use the same hose kit, SM-BH59-JK-SS, so the hydraulics should be compatible.  My major concern, however, would be that the Shimano site explicitly notes that the *ACERA* part has "braking power tuned for entry level riders."

A leak might just be down to the hose - or fittings - though, so you might want to find out if your LBS can service it for cheaper than getting in new levers.

Comment: Went to the LBS already, and the leak is happening at the oil reservoir cover, so i know its not the hose or fittings. As for the lever, the the BL-T445 is not available at my country. I have to go with a MT200 or a more expensive Deore lever. My concern is the incompatibility of the hoses.

Comment: Ah, your question wasn't clear.  If you check out the spec pages for the 2 levers (the one that's part of your component group, and the one you're considering) they have the same hose kit (SM-BH59-JK-SS).

Comment: Very well then, i'll let you know how it goes!